# Importing multiple shapefiles into one single Postgres table

Tags: postgis, shapefile

I am trying to import in one single table different shapefiles using the command:

```
 shp2pgsql -D -s 4326 -c my_shapes_table -I *.shp  > my_shapes_table.sql
```

I have tried different combinations of the parameters but what I got are always multiple tables with the name of each single file. Any idea how to get one single table only that imports all the files?

Comment: By reading the manual http://www.bostongis.com/pgsql2shp_shp2pgsql_quickguide_20.bqg you should use -a for append.

Comment: I tried that too without any luck - I don’t get how the options should be written

Comment: There seem to be examples about looping through many files on the same page. I do not find anywhere that *.shp is supported, where did you learn to use that syntax? However, I am not sure if you can actually append to dump format.

Comment: See [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136553/batch-load-multiple-shapefiles-to-postgis). If you already have the table, you don't even need the if statement, you just use the -a flag and pipe everything to psql. This is obviously bash for linux, but you would be able to do something similar in Windows.