# PostgreSQL/PostGIS: Adding attributes to a table that I can use to query with

Tags: postgis, shapefile, postgresql

Currently I have a PostGIS database that is taking in shapefiles. However, these shapefiles are converted into tables when they are imported into the database. Each shapefile deals with a farm name, field name, and year. Is there a way that I can add these attributes to be associated with the table so I could query my table by farm name and field name?

Comment: Yes, append each shape file to an existing table (there is an -a switch in shp2pgsql) and the year, name and field will just be attributes of this table, rather than  creating a new table each time.

Comment: Would you be able to refer me to any documentation that I could read about for this??

Comment: Yes, actually, I asked [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136553/batch-load-multiple-shapefiles-to-postgis) which more or less explains how to do it and an answer using ogr2ogr also.