# Using ogr2ogr to convert multiple GML files to a postgis table

Tags: postgis, gdal, postgresql, ogr2ogr, gml

I have a folder with 150 .gml (addressbase) files I need to upload to my postGIS/postgres database. After the first gml is uploaded, the rest will be appended to it to form a single table. However I don't know how to make ogr2ogr iterate through each file... currently I'm having to upload/append each cml induvidually.

My code to convert the first gml:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=admin password=password" -lco SCHEMA=test_schema "D:\path to folder\File1.gml" -progress -lco OVERWRITE=YES
```

and my code to append each subsequent gml to the first:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=admin password=password active_schema=test_schema" "D:\path to folder\File2.gml" -progress
```

This works fine but I don't want to do this another 148 times, changing File2 to File3 each time etc...

The GMLs contain point features. For use with postgis and qgis.

Comment: *ogr2ogr* should happily read all supported files from a folder if given only the directory.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't. If I remove File2.gml I get an 'unable to open datasource 'D:\path to folder\' with the following drivers.' Same goes for 'D:\path to folder' (no backslash at the end). @ThingumaBob

Comment: Ths [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136553/batch-load-multiple-shapefiles-to-postgis) refers to a similar process with shp2pgsql, for which the accepted answer deals with ogr2ogr.

Comment: There is the [Loader](https://github.com/AstunTechnology/Loader/wiki) tool from Astun which is free and worth a look if you need to do this regularly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at your examples, I assume you are working on a Windows machine. Try the following:

1. Copy/Move/Put the remaining 149 GML files in a directory, say *D:\myGMLs*.
2. Paste the codes below into a text file and save it with a `.bat` or `.cmd` extension, say *"D:\Work\do_149.cmd"*.

```
    set dirgml=D:\myGMLs

    set app=ogr2ogr
    set opt=-update -append -progress
    set dst=-f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost port=5432 dbname=testdb user=admin password=password active_schema=test_schema"

    for %%G in ("%dirgml%\*.gml") do %app% %opt% %dst% "%%G"
```

3. Open up a Command Prompt (cmd.exe) and run the bat/cmd (eg *"D:\Work\do_149"*).

The double quotes around *"%dirgml%\*.gml"* and *"%%G"* let you work with directory name and filename that have spaces in them e.g., *"D:\Project Frosty\My Snowmobile.gml"*.

Comment: can you explain the last line of that .bat code? I need to know whether I need to ammend any of it to suit my folder directories/gml file names.

Comment: @TheoF. If you had created say "abc.bat" - then you run "abc.bat". If you had created say "abc.cmd", then you run "abc.cmd". Both extensions are equivalent.

Comment: not quite what I meant, but anyway, your answer worked! thank you very much.

Comment: @TheoF Oops, sorry. Please refer to this link https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-percent.html