# shp2pgsql drop database table option doesn't work if table doesn't exist yet

Tags: postgis, shp2pgsql

#### Context

I have a [PostGIS](https://postgis.net/) database.

If I use:

```
shp2pgsql -I -s 4326 -d "my_shapefile.shp" myschema.vectordata \
| psql -h localhost -U username -d my_database -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1
```

To inject data from a [Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf%E2%80%8E) source, I got the error:

```
Shapefile type: Arc
Postgis type: MULTILINESTRING[2]
SET
SET
ERROR:  column not found in geometry_columns table
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function dropgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying,character varying) line 34 at RAISE
SQL statement "SELECT myschema.DropGeometryColumn('',$1,$2,$3)"
PL/pgSQL function dropgeometrycolumn(character varying,character varying,character varying) line 5 at SQL statement
```

If I remove the `-d` flag, it goes well.
So I guess that, as stated in the documentation;

```
-d     Drops the database table before creating a new table with the data in the Shape file.
```

it will drop the database table without checking if it exists before.
So in the case tables exist, it goes well, if not, it fails as stated before.

#### Question

How could I make it equivalent to somehow a drop "`IF EXISTS`" sql statement when dropping the database table prior to injecting new data from a [Shapefile](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf%E2%80%8E)?

#### Informations;

"`PostgreSQL 10.12 (Ubuntu 10.12-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0, 64-bit`"

"`2.4 USE_GEOS=1 USE_PROJ=1 USE_STATS=1`"

Comment: A workaround could be to run the command with -p switch first. Then you should have always something to drop with the next step. Or just send DROP TABLE with psql first. Or use ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html with -overwrite.

Comment: Adding the `-p` flag prior to the `-d` doesn't change the situation.

Comment: I did not mean that but running the whole command with -p first.

Comment: I asked a [similar question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136553/batch-load-multiple-shapefiles-to-postgis) a few years ago. The solution was to use ogr2ogr instead. The other approach, if you want to stick with shp2pgsql, is to have a batch script which checks whether the table exists or not and then run the shp2pgsql with the appropriate switch.

Comment: I've read [here](https://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) an interesting comment on using `ogr2ogr` or `shp2pgsql`: "The pgsql2shp and shp2pgsql are usually the best tools for converting back and forth between PostGIS and ESRI for 2 main reasons.". I'm still having some same issue while using `ogr2ogr`; it cannot find the postgis installation because it was set in an other schema. I don't know how to make the tool aware of that?

Comment: Actually, this: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357006/making-postgis-extension-persist-in-the-search-path-of-a-postgresql-database solves the latter. Now the tools are able to find PostGIS functions.